Use CLion Debugger with GDB with the XV6
I am working with the XV6 code base (RISC-V).
My current setup consists of using JetBrains Gateway to run a CLion instance in the WSL 2 on Windows.
Presently, I can run the command make qemu-gdb in one terminal, followed by running the command gdb-multiarch ~/XV6/kernel/kernel in another terminal. This way, I can use the debugger in that other terminal.
I want to achieve something similar where, instead of using a debugger in the second terminal, I use the Debugger of CLion.
The best I have achieved as of now is first updating the default gdb in the Toolchain as below:

Followed by the following Debug Configuration:

Now, just like before, I run make qemu-gdb in one terminal.
Then I click on the debug button, which successfully connects to the debugger, but it instantly exits With the following messages:

And a popup saying:

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to do it correctly.
